# memory leak in .net application, debugdiag analysis is not giving GC details

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory-leaks, windbg, debugdiag

We have a asp.net website hosted on IIS and If my application runs for more than a day,it uses more than 4 GB and stays like that.Currently we have a set a recycling as a work around. I am in the process of finding out the root cause of the leak using debugdiag.

**Edit:**

I tried to use windbg by following [this](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2014/03/20/investigating-aspnet-memory-dumps-for-idiots-like-me) but manual analysis did not really help.But I found out that debugdiag's automated analysis can tell you which .net obejcts are consuming most objects .Following these [articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577477.aspx) and this from Microsoft

Was expecting to see .net information like this [image: .net information in the dumps] but instead I got the error **"Your browser settings are currently prohibiting this report's scripts from running"**

I followed [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2010/01/14/debugging-native-memory-leaks-with-debug-diag-1-1/) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/02/01/analyze-a-memory-dump-using-the-debug-diagnostic-tool/) article but the analysis is not giving much details on .NET and this is a pure .NET application.I was expecting to see Memory consuming .NET objects and GC details etc.

Comment: If you cannot post some code where you might think the error lies, this is completely offtopic (since we could not possibly know where to look at)

Comment: if you do not know,debugdiag is one of the tool from microsoft to analyse memory dumps to figure out where the problem is.debugdiag on asp.net is not working,how is offtopic?

Comment: can you  mention some features of your asp.net app? .NET version? and your server? and some of your code if possible.

Comment: I am using .NET 4 runtime and it's a asp.net webforms+webapi . The memory leaking code part is that i am trying to find out by analysing using windbg or debugdiag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For debugdiag to work correctly, you have to have the same version of
>   .net framework (of the application) installed on the analyzing machine
>   as well.

Refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759636/finding-memory-leak/44867575#44867575) for more details on the analysis

Comment: Thanks for the tip.It worked when i ran in a dev machine. I was running the analysis in a different machine as my original machine was production environment.